# Интеграционный тест для Spring-контроллера. Ошибка LazyInitializationException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Есть интеграционный тест для Spring-контроллера. Использую TestRestTemplate. Вот так работает:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@Log4j2
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ClientControllerTest {

// .......

@Test
@DisplayName("[TestRestTemplate] Успешное обновление клиента")
public void updateSuccess() {
    Long id = saveClientInDB().getId();

    Client update = new Client("New_last", "New_first", "New_mid", 77, Collections.emptyList());
    ClientDto updateDto = ClientDto.valueOf(update);
    log.debug("updateDto: " + updateDto);

    String url = "http://localhost:" + port + BASE_URL + "/" + id;
    log.debug("url: " + url);

    HttpEntity<ClientDto> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(updateDto);
    ResponseEntity<ClientDto> actual = testRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, ClientDto.class, id);
    log.debug("actual: " + actual);

    assertThat(actual.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    assertThat(actual.getBody()).isNull();

    List<Client> all = clientRepository.findAll();
    // log.debug("all: " + all); // Если раскоментить то тест падает !!!!!!!

    assertThat(clientRepository.findAll()).size().isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(accountRepository.findAll()).size().isEqualTo(0);
    assertThat(cardRepository.findAll()).size().isEqualTo(0);
}

}
```

В тестовом методе есть закоментированная строчка:

```
// log.debug("all: " + all); // Если раскоментить то тест падает !!!!!!!
```

Если её раскоментировать то тест падает с такой ошибкой: **org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.bank_api.entity.Client.accounts, could not initialize proxy - no Session**

Полный текст ошибки:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.bank_api.entity.Client.accounts, could not initialize proxy - no Session

at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:621)
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)
at com.example.bank_api.entity.Client.toString(Client.java:12)
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:473)
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)
at com.example.bank_api._integration_with_TestRestTemplate.ClientControllerTest.updateSuccess(ClientControllerTest.java:251)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Вообще понять не могу. Почему это log.debug() ломает тест. При том что в данном тестовом методе несколько раз выше используется log.debug().

Comment: Судя по всему не логе проблема, но в переменной all,т.е. если ее в лог не выводить - падать не будет. Почему так - идей нет)

Comment: почему не используете MockMVC?

Answer (score 0):

Случайно наткнулся на решение. В entity-классе Client в аннотации @OneToMany надо дописать атрибуту **fetch = FetchType.EAGER** вот так:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Account> accounts;
```

Теперь работает. Х.з. почему, надо гуглить и дальше изучать вопрос, не могу объяснить пока что))

Возможно там в логе когда пишу **all**, то неявно же подразумевается **all.toString()** А при выводе сущности клиент выводится и список его счетов. Без атрибуты EAGER не хочет видать....

Comment: Если там был LAZY, то вы не очень хорошо поступили. Вы же пишите код не ради тестов. Жертвуете производительностью в угоду тестов

Comment: @ArchDemon , там не было LAZY, изначально я писал так: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client"). Я пока на начальной стадии изучения))